# How to list subcategories on category page in big-commerce?

Tags: bigcommerce

I am going to list all child categories of a parent category in big-commerce. We have to check that either this category have child categories are not when clicked. If there is child categories then list all the child categories on category page. Otherwise show products of the category. How it is possible in big-commerce ?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To display sub-categories on a category page, you must use:

```
%%SNIPPET_SubCategories%%
```

This will provide a dynamic list of sub-categories on each category page.